# Template function for collection based on member

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

I have the following structures

```
struct Obj
{
  int a;
  int b;
};
class ObjCollection
{
   map<int,Obj> collMap;
 public:
   string getCsvA();
   string getCsvB();
};
```

`getCsvA` returns a csv of all the `a` values in the objects of `collMap`. `getCsvB` returns the same for all the `b` values.

Is there a way I can template this function? The reason it becomes complicated for me is that i cannot pass the address of which member i want to generate the csv for, from outside this class ie from my client code. Is there a way to do this?
Note: I can not use C++11.

Comment: Termplating should generally be a last resort.  Why are the two existing methods you defined not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you need a function as a parameter to `getCsv` rather than templates:

Declare the function as `string getCsv(int (*selectMember)(Obj))`. Furthermore use `selectMember([...])` wherever you would have used `[...].a` in `getCsvA`.

Now you can call `getCsv` providing a method returning the right field of `Obj`, for example:

```
int selectA(Obj o)
{
    return o.a;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that i will have to pass the function in the client code.
Something like 
    objCollection.getCsv(selectA); 
    objCollection.getCsv(selectB);
That would mean that I have to expose functions selectA and selectB, right?
If my understanding is wrong, can you give me an example of how the function would be called?

Comment: You are right. In one way or the other you *have* to let the client chose which member to use - there are definitely other ways, what kind of "interface" would you prefer? I rather thought of *the client* creating those "select..." methods - is `Obj` even visible to the client?

Comment: I was thinking of having two separate interface, getCsvA and getCsvB. I guess then I can internally call the pass the appropriate selecter function. Thanks.

Comment: What is the benefit of passing a function pointer as opposed to just passing the value as an argument?

Comment: Passing a value would have been fine if I had a single object. But instead I want to pass a function which will be called on all my objects and return the appropriate value.

Comment: There's no benefit to parameterizing the behavior though, from what you've described.  Especially since the behavior is static with respect to the public fields of `Obj`.  In general, you shouldn't parameterize things that aren't necessary.

Comment: @Noel: yes, in that case internally passing the selector functions sounds like the way to go :) @Jason: it makes sense to me in respect to code deduplication; also if `Obj` turns out to get more fields, you will be happy with this design (compared to enums and ifs/switch and so on)

Answer (score 0):

While a bit inelegant, if you've just a couple fields you can reasonably have `getCsvA` and `getCsvB` call a `getCsv(A_or_B a_or_b)` function, given `enum A_or_B { A, B };`, then inside `getCsv` when you you're iterating over `collMap` say `int value = (a_or_b == A) ? iterator->a : iterator->b;`, then you put *that* `value` into your csv string.  Easier than worrying about pointers to member data, functors or templates: when you're comfortable with this level of programming, then you can worry about more abstract approaches (hopefully you'll have C++11 available then, as lambdas are nice for this).

Answer (score 0):

The skeleton of code that you have actually looks okay.  It's generally a bad idea to parameterize things that aren't necessary to parameterize.  Templates are the most powerful way, but they should really be used with equal discretion.

By adding parameters, you add more opportunities for incorrect code (incorrect function pointer, null pointer, etc...).  Using function pointers or virtual methods also creates more difficulty for the compiler in optimizing, since the code executing generally has to be resolved at runtime.

If you were using C++11 instead of C++03 though, using a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) instead of a naked `struct` would probably make sense, and you would get a templated function as a bonus.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename... Ts>
class TupleCollection {

 public:

   template<std::size_t I>
   std::string getCsv() {

     for (const auto& p : collMap) {

       std::string v = static_cast<std::string>(std::get<I>(p.second));
       ...
      }
  }

  private:

    std::map<int, std::tuple<Ts...>> collMap;

};
```

Then getting the CSV for the relevant field in a compile time safe way would be

```
tc.getCSV<0>();
tc.getCSV<1>();
```